# Seeing more of comment

Tags: php, javascript, template-lite

I retrieve comments from my database.

```
 {foreach value=users from=$comment}
    <tr>    
        <td>{$users.ADD_DATE}</td>
        <td>{$users.NAME}</td>
        {if $users.COMMENT|count_characters > 95}
        <td>{$users.COMMENT|truncate:95:"..."}<a href="#">devamı</a></td>
        {else}
          <td>{$users.COMMENT}</td>
          {/if}
        <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="checkComment[]" value={$users.ID} /></center></td>
</tr>
        {/foreach}
```

as you see above code, if comment bigger than 95  truncate and put a link. If less, not problem.

What i want is that, if comments is bigger than 95 character, user may want to click the link.When s/he clicks the link, s/he can see the full comment.

How can i do that ?

Comment: This will most likely be done using Javascript and not PHP (unless you want the user to enter another page containing the full comment).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is the best choice for this problem.

Try jTruncate:
http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=jTruncate

That should do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would probably be to use jquery and the [show/hide](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-showhide-div/&ei=ixpzT5j-IePs2gWU5KzSDg&usg=AFQjCNHOTzrL51sOIIfQFpMOj-VPDXwegA) div.

You could also create a new page and link to that page where it will show the full comments basically don't truncate the text on the new page.